# Java executeQuery returning null

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to write a method that checks my database if a user has the permission to execute a certain method.

**The response that I'm getting after executing the query it's null.**

I have the following method for doing this :

```
    public boolean checkRole(String encToken,String methodName)throws Exception, RuntimeException{
     CryptoHelper crypto = new CryptoHelper();
     SecretKeySpec key= new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
    try{
    String token = crypto.decrypt(encToken.toString(), key);
      String [] parts = token.split( ":" );
      String user = parts[0];

      String query ="SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN Permissions "
            + "ON data.Role = Permissions.Permission "
            + "where Username = '" + user + "' AND Function ='" + methodName + "')";
      res = stm.executeQuery(query);

      if(res.equals(true)){           
            System.out.println("Welcome " + user );
            return true;
          }          
  }
       catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
       }
    return false;

  }
```

I've also checked if I'm passing the correct user and methodName and that seemed to be fine.

The database structure :

```
USE DB;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id_u` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Salt` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Role` int(30)  NOT NULL,
);

--
-- Dumping data for table `data`
--

INSERT INTO `data` (`id_u`,`Username`, `Password`, `Salt`,`Role`) VALUES
(1,'Mike', 'TzBql1WR9wZjN0LoKr2OBk2majc=', '4NWwJULan8U=','1'), --- password : ThisTheFirstPassword
(2,'Cecilia', 'TzBql1WR9wZjN0LoKr2OBk2majc=', '4NWwJULan8U=','1'),
(3,'Erika', 'iubXIju+Hd+EOgIuivTx3RbRDoU=', '2MWwJULan8U=','2'),
(4,'Alice', 'mWrE8czs6KkOeP1WiMyn0NEnKGw=', '4NWSJULgn8U=','2'),
(5,'Bob', 'YNvbZBcchzXYRyRJBx5WkPmwxfo=', '4NWwJILan9U=','3'),
(6,'David', 'OPhte5nto3U+rJucbb3GUTGCSiI=', '4NWwFULan8X=','3');
COMMIT;

--
-- Table structure for table `Permissions`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Permissions`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Permissions` (
  `id_p` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Function` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Permission` int(30) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Permissions`
--

INSERT INTO `Permissions` (`id_p`, `Function`, `Permission`) VALUES
(1, 'print', 1),
(2, 'print', 2),
(3, 'print', 3),
(4, 'queue', 1),
(5, 'queue', 2),
(6, 'queue', 3),
(7, 'topQueue', 1),
(8, 'topQueue', 2),
(9, 'restart', 1),
(10, 'restart', 2);
(11, 'restart', 4);
(12, 'start', 1);
(13, 'start', 4);
(14, 'stop', 1);
(15, 'stop', 4);
(16, 'status', 1);
(17, 'status', 4);
(18, 'readConfig', 1);
(19, 'readConfig', 4);
(20, 'setConfig', 1);
(21, 'setConfig', 4);
```

Also when I'm executing the query in Mysql it does work as intended.

[image]

Comment: Where is your `PreparedStatement` and why don't you prepare it with `setString(int, String)` but instead pass a concatenated `String` as query?

Comment: `executeQuery` never returns `null` (and if a driver would do that, it would violate a basic requirement of the JDBC API). Why do you think that `res.equals(true)` would be an appropriate thing to do? A `ResultSet` will never be equal to `true`, and any decent IDE would warn you about that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I will replace res.equals(true). My logic was that I'm trying to check if the query execution will return true that's why I thought I could use that.

Comment: @deHaar I'll try to use PreparedStatement instead of concatenated String.

Comment: A query returns a result set, in your case the result set contains a row that has the value true. That doesn't mean the result set itself is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT EXISTS delivers exactly one record. So one would need:

```
  String query ="SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN Permissions "
        + "ON data.Role = Permissions.Permission "
        + "WHERE Username = ? AND Function = ?)";
  try (PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
      stm.setString(1, user);
      stm.setString(2, methodName);
      try (ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery()) {
          if (res.next()) {           
              boolean exists = res.getBoolean(1);
              if (exists) {
                  System.out.println("Welcome " + user);
              }
              return exists;
          }
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Your solution would be possible using a simpler SQL

```
  String query ="SELECT Username FROM data INNER JOIN Permissions "
        + "ON data.Role = Permissions.Permission "
        + "WHERE Username = ? AND Function = ? "
        + "LIMIT 1"; // One record only
  try (PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
      stm.setString(1, user);
      stm.setString(2, methodName);
      try (ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery()) {
          if (res.next()) {           
              System.out.println("Welcome " + user);
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
  }
```

***Note***: in first version I forgot to remove the parameter of executeQuery.

Comment: Thank you, @Joop Eggen seems like that was the problem. I tried the first solution that you provided. I understand what I was doing wrong and it even seems better to do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if(res.equals(true))
```

with

```
if(res.next())
```

Please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html for more details.

Also, you should use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` for parametrized queries. More details at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html